# PARCEL ERROR : unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version

Tags: serialization, bundler, parcel

i have my daily problem right now.
i run an oracle virtual machine with npm on my terminal, and PARCEL bundler to compile my css.
when i try to launch it to get my page view, it returns "PARCEL ERROR : unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version".
i have updated my npm and my parcel [sudo npm i -g parcel] and all seems to be good, but still not working.

questions : (for me, it seems that the parcel bundler is ok, just updated minutes ago)

- may my VM be obsolete, so that i must update her (i said "her" lol)
  *if so, may that erase my datas (website codes)?
  *am i wrong ? : may the problem be anything else, and if so, what should i do ?

excuse my poor english, and please forgive if the fix is somewhere in there, i have not found yet.

thanks for the help !

Donei

Comment: Error: Unable to deserialize cloned data due to invalid or unsupported version.
    at Object.deserialize (node:v8:269:7)
    at deserialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/serializer.js:236:26)
    at Cache.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/cache/lib/Cache.js:93:38)
    at async Transformation.readFromCache (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:631:24)
    at async Transformation.runPipelines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:412:

Comment: 29)     at async Transformation.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:316:19)
    at async Child.handleRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js:255:9)
"

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your question with the additional information if you have any. Users use comments to ask further clarification about your question. You can reply to those comments with your comments. I will suggest you to please remove your comments and add this information to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It happen to me also using node v14 and parcel 2.5.0. Solved by selecting a newer node v18 with nvm. So just

```
nvm use latest
rm -Rf node_modules
npm i
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time. I had a problem with YARN and migrating to Node V18 was the solution.